# How to quickly get gem apples

Tags: team-kirby-clash-deluxe

I want to buy the starlight equipment for my team, but it costs 113 gem apples. I really want the armor to make the super party quest easier. The gem apple tree takes to long because it only produces 10 gem apples every 12 hours.

What is a really quick way to get gem apples without purchasing any? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There arent REALLY fast ways, the only ways to get them are:

- Badges from completing bosses in some way (not easy to farm, gives only once)
- Gem apple tree, which grows by paying(!) for gem apples.

No other ways other ten buying them apart from that.
However, if you do hack your 3ds (the device I assume you are using), you can just use checkpoint to have an ungodly amount.

Comment: Who downvoted? D:

Comment: Please add more information. FYI I play on switch. Their is no Team Kirby Clash Deluxe tag.